# Google email script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to use the following function:

```
    // This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Given in a google tutorial in the following link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails
I want to change line 6 so that it functions only to a specified sheet, and not based on which one is active. It was suggested to me in another forum to change that line to:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("sheetname");
```

But the script editor could not find such a command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You must open the spreadsheet before accessing individual sheets. If your script is file-bound, try:

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name);
```

If you are using a standalone script or need to reference another spreadsheet, try:

```
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name)
```

Hope this helps.